# Yii:Pass a Javascript Variable to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I have an element in my javascript block whose value I would like to pass to php.
The variables are

> $('#datefirst').val()

and

> $('#datelast').val()

My code is (should give an idea of what am talking about)

```
<?php $datefirst = ?>$('#datefirst').val(); 
<?php $datelast = ?>$('#datelast').val();   
window.location = "<?php echo CController::createAbsoluteUrl('export/motheradmission',
array('datefirst'=>$datefirst,'datelast'=>$datelast)) ?>";
```

Any ideas that will help me accomplish this feat?

Comment: Please have a look at [server-side / client-side](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=569).

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs on the server. It (usually) generates an HTML document (possibly with embedded JavaScript). This is then delivered to the client. At this point the PHP script has finished.

The client gets the document and runs any JavaScript.

The only way to get data back to the server is to issue a new HTTP request.

You probably want to do something like:

```
window.location = "some.php?datefirst=" + encodeURIComponent(datefirst) + "&datelast=" + encodeURIComponent(datelast);
```

… and then process the submitted data in some.php.

Comment: Since the original script was redirecting the browser to another URL, Ajax would just complicate matters for no benefit in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Given you then use window.location to bounce them on to a new page, why not just continue with the javascript and add the variables to the end of the URL you're bouncing to? Such as

```
Window.location = "<code>"+"?datefirst"+('#datefirst').val()+"&datelast="+('#datelast').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign js values to php.
You can acheive the redirection like this.

```
var firstdate=$('#datefirst').val(); 
var lastdate=$('#datelast').val();  
var url = "<?php echo CController::createAbsoluteUrl('export/motheradmission',
array('datefirst'=>'#firstdate','datelast'=>'#lastdate')) ?>";
url = url.replace('#firstdate',firstdate);
url = url.replace('#lastdate',lastdate);
window.location.href=url;
```